Dynamic values to @CircuitBreaker configuration
I am using this library to implement Circuit breaker in a Kotlin app using Quarkus and the package says to use fixed values, as for example (it's just one that you can find on github):
@CircuitBreaker(requestVolumeThreshold = 4, failureRatio = 0.75, delay = 5000, successThreshold = 2)

But what happend if we want to use dynamic values?, to be  readed from a database o something like that to be able to change it on the way while the server is running.
I  don't know if make sense or not or if it  have some advantage and I would like to know yours opinions about it.

The fault tolerance annotations can be overridden through configuration, but that is read only once and so cannot change on the fly.

I understand it but it doesn't have any advantage to the project? Just curious . Thanks for your comment
